# When (if ever) should a question include general reference links?

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question in which I provided a link to Wikipedia for a term that seemed likely to be unfamiliar to many here, but now I am wondering if such was appropriate/helpful. (If I had not provided the link, I would have slightly reworded the phrase to make a web search more effective. The term was also only of secondary importance.) I am also curious about when **questions** should include links to general reference materials.

(Specialized reference links seem to be easier to evaluate for usefulness. Links in answers also seem to be easier to evaluate.)

Answer (score 5):

Sure, if you give references to your question, it makes a lot of sense. So people know what you are talking about. In a worst-case scenario, people can also see, how good or how bad you actually understand the material and adjust their answers accordingly. Besides, you do not need to explain a lot by yourself and can therefore focus on your actual question. **It is appropriate and helpful.**

Answer (score 3):

References in questions, imply that some basic research has been conducted.  As a rule some research before asking a question, leads to better questions.

Reference links in questions should always be ok.

As with anything, moderation, diversity and appropriateness should be considered.